# Styles revert back after being changed with JS code

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to set the styles of a `div` when a button is clicked. The changes occur but then they instantly revert back to the existing styling.

[View Demo](https://crobbo.github.io/tic-tac-toe-javascript/)

[Full Source Code](https://github.com/crobbo/tic-tac-toe-javascript/tree/AI-opponent)

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("js-multi-btn")) {
    gameBoard.setGameMode('multi');
    displayController.revealBoard();
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("js-single-btn")) {
    gameBoard.setGameMode('single');
    displayController.revealBoard();
  }
});

function revealBoard() {
  var btns = document.querySelector('.js-gameplay-btns');
  btns.style.display = 'none'
  var board = document.getElementById('js-board')
  board.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="js-multi-btn multi-btn">Multi Player Mode</a>
<a href="" class="js-single-btn single-btn">Single Player Mode</a>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it into a [mcve]

Comment: None of these three classes used in your JS code, are even set on any of the HTML elements in the snippet you have shown. Please do not just dump the full code on an external platform - a _proper_ minimal reproducible example of your problem always belongs directly into your question.

Comment: Sorry, wrote this question in a rush.  I've changed the HTML but I am struggling to show the issue in isolation as I don't fully understand which part is incorrect. The code snippet in the edited question is not reproducing the same error, in fact the buttons disappear as expected. The answer @mplungjan provided has helped so thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/unjsp6tm/

Change to

```
   <a href="" data-gm="multi" class="js-btn single-btn">
   <a href="" data-gm="single" class="js-btn multi-btn">
```

then

```
document.querySelector(".js-gameplay-btns").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("a");
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("js-btn")) {
    e.preventDefault()
    gameBoard.setGameMode(tgt.dataset.gm);
    displayController.revealBoard();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Just edit your answer to add a missing bracket on the `if` statement line.